# Google Checkout TIMEOUT error

Tags: php, xml, api, google-checkout

periodicly i got error in my Google Checkout Integration Console:

We encountered an error trying to access your server at http://mydomain.com/payment/ps_gcheckout.php -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'TIMEOUT' connecting to url 'http://mydomain.com/payment/ps_gcheckout.php'.

but orders are proceeded ok and i get correct response to my website, can you explain me please the reason of this error, google checkout troubleshooting gives me only "Unfortunately, we do not have a troubleshooting tip for this issue at the moment." also no documents with solutions found on web
and how it can be fixed

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The normal cause for this is if your web or database server is overloaded, and takes too long to respond to the notification callback from Google. Consider it a warning, and perhaps plan to move to a hosting platform that offers more power or better uptime performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional info about Integration Console errors:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Integration_Console_Errors.html

Generally, by checking your server logs you can see if the timeout is performance related or maybe a special case bug in your server code.

Notifications are sent until your server has acknowledged them successfully, or until 14 days have elapsed. From your description it appears that you are eventually handling notifications correctly.